# SQL Server Exists return type

Tags: sql-server, database, oop

What does the SQL Server `Exists` function return as a type?

Does `Exists` have a conceptual return type?

```
SELECT * 
FROM tableName 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * 
              FROM tableName 
              WHERE columnName LIKE 'theValue%') = 1
```

Why does this not work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[As documented in BOL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/exists-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#result-values)

> Result Types
>
> Boolean

It has a return type of boolean but this is just an internal datatype currently you can't declare columns or variables of that datatype.

Or use it in comparisons - even against another boolean.

```
where exists(select 1) = exists(select 1)
```

Also fails.

SQL Server doesn't implement the SQL Standard boolean datatype yet - the closest equivalent is `bit` but this is not a true boolean.

Answer (score 2):

Exists specifies a subquery to test for the existence of rows and returns boolean(True if any row exists else false).
[Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/exists-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#result-values)
So your code should be

```
SELECT * 
FROM tableName 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * 
          FROM tableName 
          WHERE columnName LIKE 'theValue%')
```

This will return all rows from table 'tableName' ***IF*** any one of the rows has 'columnName ' as 'theValue%' ***ELSE*** none of the rows will be returned.